# How do I unwrap an NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject optional()?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to send a POST request in Swift

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.example.com/token")

let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

let params = ["client_id":client_id, "redirect_uri":redirect_uri, "client_secret":client_secret, "code":code, "grant_type":"authorization_code"] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
var err: NSError?
request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
println(request.HTTPBody)

var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, ...
```

when I `println(request.HTTPBody)` I get NSDATA wrapped in an optional

```
Optional(<7b22636f 6465223a 22765930 6b575348...)
```

And the response I get indicates that the api isn't understanding the body as it states that "The required \"client_id\" parameter is missing"

How do I unwrap the NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject optional?

~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~

**EDIT:**
I dug further and focused on the HTTPBody lines:

```
let params = ["client_id":client_id, "redirect_uri": redirect_uri, "client_secret":client_secret, "code":code, "grant_type":"authorization_code"] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
var err: NSError?
let body = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)!
request.HTTPBody = body
println(body)
println(request.HTTPBody)
```

println(body) prints out an unwrapped variable... `<7b22636f 6465223a 224a4e46 316f4a48`
println(request.HTTPBody) is an optional... `Optional(<7b22636f 6465223a 224a4e46 316f4a48`

How do I get around this?

Comment: There is nothing to "get around". It is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I `println(request.HTTPBody)` I get NSDATA wrapped in an optional

There is no error or problem here. Consult the documentation. An NSMutableURLRequest's `HTTPBody` *is* an NSData wrapped in an Optional. What's happening is exactly what you should expect.

If you're having a problem, fine, figure out what it is and ask about it; but this isn't it.

Comment: Exactly. Now you can focus on why your request isn't _working_. :))))

Answer (score 1):

The **!** operator unwraps optional types into their respective non-nullable types. the line 
    let body = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)!

assigns body a **NSData** object, unwrapped from the expected return type **NSData?**

request.HTTPBody is of type **NSData?**, and so this line

```
request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)!
```

unwraps the **NSData?** return from NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject to type **NSData**, only to be placed back into a container of type **NSData?**. The optional **NSData?** container of course can except the **NSData** value, but any reference to request.HTTPBody will return **NSData?**

If you wish to remove the optional wrapping of request.HTTPBody you must unwrap it any time you wish to express it.

```
println(request.HTTPBody!)
```

Or as you did above, store the unwrapped version locally and reference that variable!

```
let body = request.HTTPBody!
println(body)
```

Comment: I tried that first. It still came through as Optional(). I should have written that in the example above...

Comment: You exclamation mark makes no difference. You are assigning _into_ an Optional. Thus the result will always be an Optional. And there is nothing wrong with that.